# FME DWGStyler "specified block '...' is not defined in AutoCAD file"

Tags: fme-form, dwg, dwg-styler, block, fme-transformer

In a `DWGStyler`transformer I connect DWG/DXF Template File to a Published Parameter `$(TEMPLATE_FILE)`:

[image]

The Template file exists and contains a block named `kreuzchen` which I am able to choose in the `DWGStyler` Parameters 'Block Name':

[image]

So, undoublty the block 'kreuzchen' exists in the template file.

So far so good, but running the workspace give the following error message:

```
Dynamically creating layer `koordinaten_auf_flurstuecken'
Specified block 'kreuzchen' is not defined in AutoCAD file.  Skipping feature
... Last line repeated 9 times ...
```

and below:

```
Processing AutoCAD File...
AutoCAD Writer: 165 feature(s) were rejected and not written to the destination dataset
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing rsp.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First guess is that you also need to specify the template file in the Writer parameters - check out the Navigator window and you'll see a template file setting. Make sure it is set.